# Explicit family of polynomials describing embedded torus in complex projective space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, elliptic-curves

Let $\mathbb{C}^n / \Lambda$ be a complex torus of complex dimension $n$, with the lattice $\Lambda$ satisfying all the nice properties required for it to embed in some $\mathbb{CP}^N$. What are some explicit examples of such tori, by giving an actual family of polynomials cutting it out, for $n > 1$?

I know for the "easy" case $n=1$, where we just have elliptic curves, we get the standard cubic $y^2 = x^3 + ax + b$. (Side question: this describes a curve in $\mathbb{C}^2$ and is not a homogeneous polynomial, so it doesn't immediately give an embedding in $\mathbb{CP}^2$, where I believe it usually lies in. Does this cubic induce a natural, single homogeneous polynomial whose solution set in $\mathbb{CP}^2$ is the embedded elliptic curve?)

What possible polynomials, and how many, would we get when describing the embedding of a complex torus of dimension $2$, let's say?

Comment: Elliptic curves don't embed into $\mathbb{C}^2$. More generally, holomorphic functions on compact Riemann surfaces are constant. The cubic you wrote is the affine part $z \neq 0$ of the elliptic curve embedded into $\mathbb{CP}_{x,y,z}^2$.

Comment: For an explicit embedding of an abelian surface into $\mathbb{P}^4$ see the Horrocks-Mumford bundle, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horrocks%E2%80%93Mumford_bundle.

Comment: @Daniel Yeah the solution set of that cubic isn't a torus in the usual sense (or any sense) in $\mathbb{C}^2$, that much is clear, but I'm talking about using that cubic to describe a curve (and thus a homogeneous polynomial) in $\mathbb{CP}^2$

Comment: @PaulCusson To get the equation for the cubic curve in $\mathbb{CP}^2$, we homogenize: $y^2z = x^3 + axz^2 + bz^3$.

Comment: The theory developped in the articles of D. Mumford, "On the equations defining abelian varieties I,II,II" in principle allows an explicit computation of equations cutting out abelian varieties in some projective spaces. In particular, he shows that quadratic and cubical equations suffice. I have never seen a complete list of such equations in a special case though (perhaps because there are to many). See also Birkenhake-Lange, "Complex Abelian varieties" (Springer), chap. 10.

Comment: In Sasha's comment, the abelian surface arises as the zero set of a section of a vector bundle, which is not a sum of ${\cal O}(k)$. So this is explicit in a sense, but not in the sense that explicit homogenous equations are provided.

Comment: @DamianRössler: Right, but this vector bundle has a very explicit presentation, so it shouldn't be hard to obtain the equations of the surface.